# Piecewise function in sympy

Tags: sympy, piecewise

I would like to define the piecewise function below using the sympy module and then calculate a Fourier series for it.

Unfortunately I have no idea how exactly this works and have not found anything helpful on the internet.

Thanks in advance
[piecewise function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoBbt.png)

Comment: Have you tried reading the SymPy tutorial?

Comment: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#sympy-functions-elementary-piecewise